# howto add a textBlock to a silverlight/XNA WP7 app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, xna

hi i have a question about the silverlight/xna template for wp7 programming.

i start a new projekt and then draw some content in the game screen. and then i add the following to the xaml page of GamePage:

```
<Grid Height="800" Name="grid1" Width="480" Background="White">
    <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Lifes: 3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" />
    <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="393,12,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Points: 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" />
</Grid>
```

but the problem is i dont see the textBlock and i dont know why.
who can give me a hint?

Comment: What page orientation are you in (landscape by any chance)?

Comment: SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"

Comment: i have the anser, i must use a UIElementRenderer

Comment: That *is* rather fundamental - the code sample for SL/XNA on MSDN should walk you through all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your code look anything like this?

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Height="800" Name="grid1" Grid.Row="1" Width="480" Background="White">
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Lifes: 3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" />
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="367,12,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Points: 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Because I tested this and it works fine. Here's the result:

- dark theme: http://dyp.im/5Hn23wjJk
- light theme: http://dyp.im/hXtmaBQEuv1

**Update:**

Otherwise you should provide some other code which might cause the problem.

Comment: Nice guess given the lack of info in the question but OP has said he forgot to use `UIElementRenderer`

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comment...  -_-'

Answer (score 0):

TIP: There was a typo in initial question text. @gurehbgui asked why he isn't seeing the **textBox** (when he meant TextBlock). That is the reason why this answer is here. After the typo has been fixed this answer became no longer relevant.

You are using a `TextBlock` control.

You should use `TextBox` to have an edit field for a text element.

Also, since the Foreground is set to Black, a control may not be visible on a black background. You can use Silverlight Spy application to inspect the WP7 GUI layout and debug such problems. Spy supports trial period.

Comment: i want to have a textBlock (like a label). why should i use textBox? dont want user input.

Comment: In your question you explicitly mention "but the problem is i dont see the textBox and i dont know why." I think you should be more careful with question description before you downvote an attempt to help you ;)

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov have a +1 from me for effort :-)